# Invalid object name while execute store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
execute ps_core.dbo.import_xlsx '.xlsx', '%Active_PDP_Context_MMS.xlsx%', 
'ps_core.dbo.Active_PDP_Context_MMS', 'D:\kerjaan\PS_CORE\20141227\TABLE\' ;
```

and result like this
Invalid object name 'ps_core.dbo.Active_PDP_Context_MMS'.

what should i do ??

thanks

Comment: Your statement doesn't use any such object. Does your stored procedure try to use the `'ps_core.dbo.Active_PDP_Context_MMS'` value as a table? Does this table exist? Where is the code of the stored procedure? Where does this error occur? What is the *full* error message including the location?

Answer (score -1):

See this link [Execute(Transact SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

You need to explicitly set your parameter values using =

Comment: First, you don't need to do that. Second, the error message doesn't refer to the parameters - it says that it can't find a table or view.